# Matrix transposition of a string

Tags: javascript, strings, matrix

Per a [Reddit Daily Programming Challenge](http://www.reddit.com/r/dailyprogrammer/comments/1m1jam/081313_challenge_137_easy_string_transposition/), I am performing a matrix transposition on a string using JavaScript.

Example input: 'The quick brown fox jumped over the lazy dog'

Output:

> ```
> Tqbfjotld
> hurouvhao
> eioxmeezg
>  cw pr y
>  kn e
>     d
> ```

While my code works, I wanted to know:

1. From a readability standpoint, would it be better to break the code up into smaller functions?
2. If there's anything in the code that can be simplified.

```js
transposeString('The quick brown fox jumped over the lazy dog');

function transposeString(str) {

  if (str.indexOf(' ') === -1) {
    var map = Array.prototype.map;

    var output = map.call(str, function (char) {
        return char + '\n';
    });
    return output.join('');
  } else {
    var master = [],
        longestWord = '';

    words = str.split(' ');

    words.forEach(function(word) {
      if (word.length >= longestWord.length) longestWord = word;
    });

    longestWord.split('').forEach(function() {
      master.push([]);
    });

    var treatedWords = words.map(function (word) {
      if (word.length < longestWord.length) {
        var spaces = Array(longestWord.length - word.length + 1).join(' ');
        return word = word + spaces;
      } else {
        return word;
      }
    });

    treatedWords.forEach(function (word) {
      var n = 0;
      word.split('').forEach(function (char) {
        master[n].push(char);
        n++;
      });
    });

    master.forEach(function (arr) {
      console.log(arr.join(''));
    });

    return;
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you asked if the code could be simplified or made more readable, let's explore other programming styles.

(Note: Remarks in my [first review](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/a/32974/9357) about handling special cases and the returning a value still apply.)

---

First, I would like to point out that a "bland" solution, building the output one character at a time, would actually be slightly shorter than your original:

```
function transposeString(str) {
    if (str == null) return str;

    var words = str.split(' ');
    var out = [];
    for (var c = 0; ; c++) {
        var line = [];
        var done = true;
        for (var w = 0; w < words.length; w++) {
            if (c < words[w].length) {
                done = false;
                line.push(words[w].charAt(c));
            } else {
                line.push(' ');
            }
        }
        if (done) {
            break;
        } else {
            out.push(line.join(''));
        }
    }
    return out.join("\n");
}
```

---

Your solution feels a little like functional programming, though not quite.  What if you go all the way with functional programming?  Your solution was already quite close; you just need to replace `.forEach()` with `.map()`.  Here's how it could look:

```
function transposeString(str) {
    if (str == null) return str;

    // Wrapper for String.length
    function length(word) { return word.length; };

    // range(3) -> [0, 1, 2]
    // http://stackoverflow.com/a/11128802/1157100
    function range(n) {
        return Array(n).join().split(',').map(function(e, i) { return i; });
    };

    var words = str.split(' ');
    var maxWordLength = Math.max.apply(null, words.map(length));

    // These functions could be anonymous; I've named them for clarity
    return range(maxWordLength).map(function outputLineUsingNthChar(n) {
        return words.map(function nthCharWithSpacePadding(word) {
            return return n < word.length ? word.charAt(n) : ' ';
        }).join('');
    }).join("\n");
}
```

That is already shorter, even though JavaScript makes `max(words.length)` and `range()` awkward.  If you use a library like [Underscore.js](http://underscorejs.org/) to provide support for [`max()`](http://underscorejs.org/#max) and [`range()`](http://underscorejs.org/#range), it could be very compact.  I'd take advantage of that compactness as an opportunity to comment generously.

```
function transposeString(str) {
    if (str == null) return str;

    var words = str.split(' ');
    var maxWordLength = _.max(_.pluck(words, 'length'));
    return _.range(maxWordLength).map(
        // Generate a line of output using the nth character of each word
        function outputLineUsingNthChar(n) {
            return words.map(
                // Extract the nth character of a word, space-padded if needed
                function nthCharWithSpacePadding(word) {
                    return n < word.length ? word.charAt(n) : ' ';
                }
            ).join('');
        }
    ).join("\n");
}
```

Answer (score 2):

[Here you go, with comments.](http://jsbin.com/ihUnUFU/1/edit?js,console)

Obviously, in production I would have only a handful of comments and not the exhaustive ones I put here. However this is the sort of points I might make during a code review.

When I write code I optimize for it for communicating to a human reader what I intend the code to do. In other words - I want it to read like an essay. Therefore, I extract anything detail-heavy into small helper methods at the bottom of the script. The idea is that someone should open my script and the first thing they see should give them a top-level overview of the general flow of logic.

I didn't comment at all on your solution itself, instead just cleaning up the algorithms that were already there.

```
transposeString('The quick brown fox jumped over the lazy dog');

//Always comment public apis with usage and your intent when writing it.

//Transpose a string of words into a vertical matrix
//from http://www.reddit.com/r/dailyprogrammer/comments/1m1jam/081313_challenge_137_easy_string_transposition/
function transposeString(str) {
  // the ~ (ones complement) operator makes indexOf work like 'contains'
  // ~(-1) == 0, ~(x != -1) != 0
  // not sure why you need this condition at all however in terms of the problem - seems like everything
  //would just work
  if (!~str.indexOf(' ')) 
    //definitely don't have two large branches of conditional logic in the same function, put them 
    //in separate well-named functions
    //Also always prefer to return early to get the simple paths out of the way in conditional logic. 
    //The whole "single point of exit" advice is from back in the day of monolithic functions and gotos all over the place
    return makeVerticalString(str);

  //My preference is to use a single var block with everything aligned and commas preceeding
  //the terms. I have good reasons for this but not anything that I care to get into without
  //being super-pedantic. It's ok to have a different style here.
  var  words            = str.split(' ')         //you were misssing var here
      ,longestWord      = getLongestWord(words)  //give algorithms their own function

      //word matrix - I recommend commenting this so that you know it's a matrix and not a flat array
      //also note that it is much cleaner to use a map than a forEach and explicit push
      //When you see array.push() anywhere it can almost always be cleaned up with a map
      ,transposedMatrix = longestWord.split('').map(function() { return [] })                     

      //give a name to the thing that you're doing here and extract the algorithm to its own function
      //also rename 'treated' to 'padded' to be more explicit
      ,paddedWords = words.map(padWordsShorterThan(longestWord.length));
      ;
  //again, move the actual algorithm to its own labeled function
  paddedWords.forEach(addEachLetterToARow(transposedMatrix));

  transposedMatrix.forEach(function (arr) {
    console.log(arr.join(''));
  });
  //no need for return if you're not returning anything

  //A line to deliniate private helper functions
  //////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
  function makeVerticalString(str) {
    //You're reducing an array to a single value so really reduce is what you want here
    Array.prototype.reduce.call(str, function(m, c) { return m+c+'\n'}, '')
  }

  function getLongestWord(words) {
    //again going from an array to a single value - we can use reduce here
    return words.reduce(function(longest, thisWord){ return thisWord.length >= longest.length ? thisWord : longest}, '');
  }

  //a function that returns a function can be a good tool for controlling scope while keeping things readable
  //note that the inner function still has a name so that it shows up properly in callstack traces  (rather than "anonymous")
  function padWordsShorterThan(threshold) { return function padWordsShorterThan(word) { 
    if (word.length >= threshold)
      return word;        
    //no need for else clauses when you return early
    return word + repeatStr(" ", longestWord.length - word.length + 1);
  }}
  function repeatStr(str, times) {
    //you have a neat little way of implementing a character repeat but its difficult to read - drop it in its own method
    return Array(times).join(str)
  }


 //Naming anonymous functions not only helps make clear what they're doing
 //but makes them show up named in a debugging callstack rather than "anonymous"
 //Rule of thumb - name anonymous functions that are doing significant logic
 function addEachLetterToARow(matrix) { return function addEachLetterToARow(word) {
    var n = 0;
    word.split('').forEach(function addToRow(char) {
      matrix[n].push(char); //note that you have a possible error condition here where matrix[n] does not exist. Do you want to check for that explicitly?
      n+=1; //I agree with Doug Crockford that ++ is wierd and error-prone. += reads much better in my opinion
    });
  } }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

I would consider it bad form for your function to `console.log()` its output instead of returning a value, because it severely harms code reusability.

I don't think that the one-word case deserves special treatment, since it's just a trivial optimization of the general case.  Even the empty string doesn't need special handling.  A `null` might deserve a special case, if you decide to handle it.

You omitted the `var` keyword when defining `words`.

Instead of appending empty arrays to `master` using `.forEach()`, you could define it all at once using `.map()`:

```
var master = longestWord.split('').map(function() { return []; });
```

The name `treatedWords` is insufficiently self-documenting.  I suggest `paddedWords`.

```
function transposeString(str) {
    if (str == null) return null;

    var words = str.split(' ');

    var longestWord = '';
    words.forEach(function(word) {
        if (word.length >= longestWord.length) longestWord = word;
    });

    var master = longestWord.split('').map(function() { return []; });

    var paddedWords = words.map(function (word) {
        if (word.length < longestWord.length) {
            var spaces = Array(longestWord.length - word.length + 1).join(' ');
            return word = word + spaces;
        } else {
            return word;
        }
    });

    paddedWords.forEach(function (word) {
        var n = 0;
        word.split('').forEach(function (char) {
            master[n].push(char);
            n++;
        });
    });

    return master.map(function (line) {
        return line.join('');
    }).join("\n");
}
```